# To check if string A matching String B exactly in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I have two strings in Tcl.

```
set A "A-1 Precision Machining"
set B "Xyz & a"
```

Now I want to check if my two different output is matching exactly or not.

if `$A = $B` or not.

How I can check this in Tcl?

Initially I am using:

```
if { [string match $B $A] }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a log or something?

Answer (score 8):

If you want to compare the variable literally you can use

```
[string equal $B $A]
```

This will compare the string character-by-character and return 1 if `$B` and `$A` is identical and return 0 if not. [TCL string equal](http://wiki.tcl.tk/4075)

If the string is lexicographical you can use

```
[string compare $B $A]
```

This will perform a character-by-character comparison of strings `$B`and `$A`. Returns -1, 0, or 1, depending on whether `$B`is lexicographical less than, equal to, or greater than `$A`.  [TCL string compare](http://wiki.tcl.tk/10163)

You can also use the traditional statement

```
if {$B == $A} {
    // Codes...
}
```

Comment: In the last case, you could also use the eq operator instead of ==. The difference is that == compiles to the general equality instruction, while eq and string equal compile to the specific string equality instruction.

Comment: using `==` for string comparison can lead to unintended things like `"0" == "0.0e0"`. If you use Tcl > 8.5, use `eq`.